# Ajax reply javascript not functioning for validation

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

am trying to generate report through dynamically generated form. Through `XMLHttpRequest` the form loads well but the validation against the form fields wont work. I have tried `eval()` it works only during load time ( like `eval(alert("hi")`) but not on dom objects , think some scope problem. The form fields are dynamically generated and so its validation based on selection and availability role in database.

The code of two files is attached below

```
<script>

function showUser(str)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    var s= xmlhttp.responseText;

    parseScript1(s);
    parseScript(s);
   }

  }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","test2.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }


   function parseScript1(_source) {
var source = _source;
var scripts = new Array();

 // Strip out tags
 while(source.indexOf("<script") > -1 || source.indexOf("</script") > -1) {
    var s = source.indexOf("<script");
    var s_e = source.indexOf(">", s);
    var e = source.indexOf("</script", s);
    var e_e = source.indexOf(">", e);

    // Add to scripts array
    scripts.push(source.substring(s_e+1, e));
    // Strip from source
    source = source.substring(0, s) + source.substring(e_e+1);
  }
var k = "<script> "+ scripts +"<\/script>";

    document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=k ;



 // Return the cleaned source
 return source;
  }




    function parseScript(_source) {
     var source = _source;
      var scripts = new Array();

 // Strip out tags
 while(source.indexOf("<script") > -1 || source.indexOf("</script") > -1) {
    var s = source.indexOf("<script");
    var s_e = source.indexOf(">", s);
    var e = source.indexOf("</script", s);
    var e_e = source.indexOf(">", e);

    // Add to scripts array
    scripts.push(source.substring(s_e+1, e));
    // Strip from source
    source = source.substring(0, s) + source.substring(e_e+1);
}

 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=source;


// Return the cleaned source
return source;
}


function valid()
  {
  eval(validate());
  }




      </script>
<div id="txtHint1"><b>javascript will appear here</b></div>
<form>
<div id="nons1" >
<select id="nope1" name="users" onchange="showUser(this)">
<option value="">Select a option:</option>
<option value="1">not working here</option>

</select>
</div>
</form>

<div id="txtHint"><b>Select the value .</b></div>
```

test2.php

```
    echo "<p>This form works fine singly  not with xmlhttprequest";

    echo'<form name="frm" method="post" action="test2.php" onsubmit="return(eval(validate()));">';
    echo '<input value="" name="kfrm19" type="text">';
    echo '<input name="save" value="submit" type="submit"></form>';

echo '<script>
function validate(){
if( document.frm.kfrm19.value.trim()=="")
   {
     alert( "If you can see this message .its working..." );
     document.frm.kfrm19.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
}


</script>';



 ?>
```

Comment: `if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }` - fyi, this is pointless. if the user has an ancient browser where XHR is not defined, your code will fail due to `xmlhttp` being undefined.

Comment: confused if I omit the part "if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {  }
and continue with the below it wont work
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: fyi I am using the firefox 22 or other updated browser and  Internet explorer is not used.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function validate(){
if(document.frm.kfrm19.value.length == 0)
   {
     alert("If you can see this message .its working...");
     document.frm.kfrm19.focus();
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: base on you code, i think you want the user to interact with the `<select>` tag, then right after selecting, the `div` with `id="txtHint1"` will add a form called `frm` from the test2.php? then from that form, you want to validate if the user input something on in`put type=text` in that form?

Comment: Its Done simply use eval there  solution at : http://www.coderanch.com/t/117983/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Execute-JavaScript-function-present-HTML